# Uninitialized constant in application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model class in my Rails application called: UserAction
In that model I have a constant (which I use as an enum):

```
class UserAction < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class UserActionType
    ACTION1 = "action1"
    ACTION2 = "action2"
end
```

when I try to use that constant:

```
if some_action == UserActionType::ACTION1
```

in the application controller I get the following error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant ApplicationController::UserActionType)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the `UserActionType` class, actually you need to require the file in which it is written. For models or wherever autoloading is configured, Rails makes it easier by autoloading files. For example, if `UserAction` is encountered, Rails look for a file called user_action.rb in models or wherever you have autoloading configured and require that file automatically. So, in your case, you can make a new file called `user_action_type.rb` in `app/models` and paste your `UserActionType` class there. Then, this error will not occur.

Comment: but if I'll add app/models/user_action_type.rb then ill have to create a table for it in the DB and i only use that class as an enum replacement...

Comment: Just declare the class without inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base. You only need a database table for ActiveRecord models.

Comment: @ran...You dont have to create a table for it if you are not extending `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Comment: @ran...Also if you feel that `UserActionType` should go with `UserAction`, you can declare the class inside the UserAction class and call it like `UserAction::UserActionType::ACTION1`.